# Is it possible to securely embed all encrytion settings on a encrypted file?

Tags: c#, .net, security, encryption

I have used many file encryption software’s, what I have noticed is either the application only one encryption algorithm or once the file is send to the respected user he/she has to use the same settings using which the file is encrypted in the first place. I am planning to develop a app in C# that supports multiple algorithms and settings etc.

My question is it possible to securely embed all the settings other than the password in the encrypted file so that the user can decrypt the file with just entering the password and need not know all the setting that were used to encrypt the file. Furthermore I would like to include the functionality of self-decryption archive that will use the functionality mentioned earlier.

I would like to embed the salt, hash and the encryption algorithm used!

Please guide me proper direction.

Comment: Is it your code encrypting and decrypting the file?

Comment: What use would that serve? Any hacker that is competent enough to decrypt a file with a symmetric key can thus discover the rest of the settings and decrypt the file anyway.

Comment: @Liam ya my code dose the encryption and decryption.

Comment: @RoyDictus Of course Roy that's true but then again if a hacker is competent won't he be able to do it anyway for any symmetric key, i guess why i wanted this feature in the first place is because the end user won't have to remember all the different settings used by different users. Just the password!

Comment: If the password is the only "thing to know" necessary to decrypt, you can just use a symmetric algorithm and be done with it. No need to complicate matters further.

Answer (score 1):

You have the *file to encrypt* and the settings you want it to be encrypted.
Then just encrypt the file and add some metadata to it, where you describe the settings to decrypt it.

Once the user enteres the correct password, you read the metadata and try to decrypt the file.
You can even encrypt your metadata with the password.

Answer (score 1):

When you output your encrypted 'message' stream tack on your information at the beginning so the stream looks, for example, like this:

```
[EncryptionAlgorithm] - 4 bytes (for example)
[salt len] - 4 bytes(ish)
[salt] - however many bytes your alg needs
[Encrypted Data len] - 8 bytes(ish)
[Encrypted Data Blob] - however long it is
[hash] - final however many bytes it needs to be
```

Also, as a tip, I'd say encrypt your KEY as the first part of the encrypted block (the first 256 bytes for standard AES). That way you can decrypt -> check that the first 256 bytes are equal to the key supplied by the user -> continue.

Also, if you're using passwords read up on MSDN about the key-from-a-password-generating algorithms supplied in the .NET FCL (Rfc2898DeriveBytes).

Hope that gives you an idea of an approach that could work?